# Master page and content page communication in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

suppose i have one dowpdown in master page and i want that when user select any item from that dropdown then a postback will occur and the selected item text will be dispalyed in the label of content page. please help me with sample code.

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add the following directive to content page:

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="path to master page" %>
```

Add public property ih master page code-behind file:

```
public DropDownList DropDownList
{
    get { return dropDownList; }
}
```

Add event handler in content page:

```
Master.DropDownList.SelectedIndexChanged += OnSelectedIndexChanged;
```

Assign Master.DropDownList.SelectedValue to Label.Text in event hanlder.

Answer (score 3):

On the Master Page:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="someDropDown" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
<asp:ListItem Text="Bob" Value="Bob"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="John" Value="John"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="Mark" Value="Mark"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

On any other page in the aspx:

```
<asp:Label ID="userLabel" runat="server"/>
```

On any other page, in the codebehind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList thisDropDown = this.Master.FindControl("someDropDown") as DropDownList;
        userLabel.Text = thisDropDown.SelectedValue;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just one sample

MasterPageCode:

```
Public Class MyMasterPage
inherits Page (or MasterPage?)

public readonly property MyDropDown as DropDown
end Property

End Class
```

Page COde

```
Public Class MyContentPage
inherits Page

Public Overrides Sub OnLoad
       dim drop as DropDown = CType(Me.MasterPage, MyMasterPage).MyDropDown
       AddHandler drop.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf someprocedure
End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to be looking at something like this...

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/969a11b2-a5a4-4a51-852a-003fd40bbd68/access-master-page-contro.aspx